# Can't open file on macOS - FileNotFoundException, Operation not permitted

Tags: java, macos, file-permissions, macos-big-sur

It's a simple program:

```
new FileInputStream("/Users/me/Desktop/foo.png")
```

I'm trying to run it from IntelliJ and I get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/me/Desktop/foo.png (Operation not permitted)

The unix perms are the usual `rw-r--r--`. It's something to do with macOS's extra security.

How can I open files in Java programs on macOS now?

This is macOS 11.0 beta (Big Sur). Maybe it was happening before 11.0 too; I don't know.

Comment: You are probably running into [Transparency Consent and Control (TCC)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673/what-and-how-does-macos-mojave-implement-to-restrict-applications-access-to-pers/332686#332686). I'd try granting Full Disk Access to IntelliJ in System Preferences -> Security & Privacy pane -> Privacy tab.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, It helped fixing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You're running into a MacOS specific issue. Checking classic POSIX permissions isn't quite enough with MacOS, since the operating system introduced a number of mechanisms to provide fine-grained control as well as security.

**Access Control Lists**

POSIX permissions provide for three groupings to which access may be controlled: owner, group and everyone else. ACLs, on the other hand, allow for the creation of Access Control Entities, which maybe defined in a number of ways. This isn't a *NIX primer, so let's just get to the meaty bits. To check ACL, pull up a terminal session, navigate to the directory containing your target file and type:

```
ls -le foo.png
```

You should see POSIX permissions, followed by a numbered list of ACL rules. If your account is affected by one of those rules, you can remove the rule as follows:

```
sudo chmod -a# num foo.png
```

where `num` is the numerical identifier for the offending rule.

**File Flags**

File flags are another parallel permissions system. Using terminal again, try:

```
ls -lO foo.png
```

NOTE: the flag is lowercase letter L followed up uppercase letter O. Con't confuse one or the other for numerals 1 or 0.

You'll again see POSIX info, followed by a string describing any flags pertaining to the file in question. The flags you care about are `uchg` and `schg` (denoting user immutability flag and system immutability flag, respectively).

You can get rid of these flags as follows:

```
sudo chflags nouchg foo.png
sudo chflags noschg foo.png
```

**Extended Attributes**

Check your file for extended attributes like so:

```
xattr -l $foo.png
```

Remove all extended attributes like so:

```
sudo xattr -c $foo.png
```

**System Integrity Protection**

System Integrity Protection may have designated your file as "rootless." Check the status at the terminal with:

```
ls -l@ foo.png
```

Clearing the rootless flag is a bit more painful. Boot via recovery disk, pull up a terminal, navigate to your file and type:

```
sudo xattr -d com.apple.rootless foo.png
```

I'm no sysadmin, but at least one of these things should cover your issue, assuming you've verified that your account has POSIX permissions and the file isn't just simply locked via Finder (Command-I, look for the little checkbox in the corner).

Comment: Super useful answer because I always forget all these different file attributes/flags. But in this case I believe it was that IntelliJ was running in the "sandbox". I opened a file in the Desktop, using the file open dialog in the IDE, and the error went away. I think the file open dialog gives the app permission to go outside the sandbox to read the file. I'm looking for a way to reset that permission now, to test this. Restarting IntelliJ did not reset it.