# Android Studio on Mac fails to build with: java.io.FileNotFoundException (Operation not permitted)

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

I'm facing an issue when trying to build my app on Android Studio. This happens every time I make a code change and then attempt to build.

I can **temporarily** fix the issue by invalidating the cache and restarting + cleaning + rebuilding. But then I make another code change and the issue arrises again.

Here is a part of the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/Kes.Walker/.../app/build/intermediates/javac/productionDebug/classes/.../databinding/ExpandedEventItemBinding.class (Operation not permitted)
at com.google.common.io.Files$FileByteSource.openStream(Files.java:130)
at com.google.common.io.Files$FileByteSource.openStream(Files.java:120)
at com.google.common.io.ByteSource.openBufferedStream(ByteSource.java:105)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.JacocoTaskDelegate$JacocoWorkerAction.run(JacocoTaskDelegate.java:379)
... 28 more
```

Note that the error will come up for different classes each time, it is not an issue with the contents of the class. But the issue does seem to always come from the `app/build/` directory.

I am running this on the following Android Studio version:

```
Android Studio 4.2
Build #AI-202.7660.26.42.7322048, built on April 29, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by N/A
macOS 10.16
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 12
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
```

I figure maybe this is a permissions issue? But I have admin rights on this PC and have granted Android Studio full disk access.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64179397/cant-open-file-on-macos-filenotfoundexception-operation-not-permitted.

Comment: Please try this way. Zip the project. Unzip the project under different name. Open the unzipped project folder and delete folders: `.idea` and `build`. Then go to `app` folder and delete `build` folder. Now, open android studio and try open this project. Wait till the project finish indexing. Let me know if it fixed the problem. Additional step, please check if something requires `allow` permission as it is as an sample: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIzzX.png

Comment: @deadfish - I've tried this before, it sometimes does fix the issue temporarily but when the folders are recreated automatically, the issue pops up again.

Comment: I have another suspicion. Try moving the project to a folder so that the absolute path is as short as possible. Your log says about path `/Users/Kes.Walker/.../app/build/`. What is the total path name?

Comment: @deadfish - The total character count is only 190. This should be okay?

Comment: The error seems temporary. It could be the antivirus or the source code manager (git or anything else) . The patch version of Android Studio is not mentioned. The file change triggers some conflict. Updating versions could help.

Comment: @ConstantinKonstantinidis - gone back and forth with the Android Studio versions, upgraded and downgraded, still get the same error.

Comment: Are you on git ? Or is the project on the iCloud (or similar) ? The file mentioned in the error should be a modified file. A message similar to "indexing paused" would hint at the conflict.

Comment: Same issue, restart my Mac fix it, don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue in bindings as the kapt was not able to generate the bindings,
First of all I recommend to upgrade to Android studio Arctic Fox

> Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Build
> #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7583922, built on July 27, 2021 Runtime version: 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189 amd64 VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation Windows 10 10.0 GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
> Memory: 1280M Cores: 4 Registry:
> external.system.auto.import.disabled=true Non-Bundled Plugins:
> org.sonarlint.idea, com.weirddev.testme, org.jetbrains.kotlin

If the issue persists then.

Go to your app-level build.gradle
At the top
Plugins should be as follows:

> plugins {
> id 'com.android.application'
> id 'kotlin-android'
> id 'kotlin-kapt' }

If still the issue persists then check the XML layout of your "ExpandedEventItem"
Please fix that error then the filenotfound will be vanished.

Sometime we copy and paste the XML and if we have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

twice in any XML the kapt throws exception.

Comment: The binding classes are being generated just fine, even though it is a `java.io.FileNotFoundException` the main issue is the 'operation not permitted' message acomidating the exception.

Comment: Ah! Got it. If you closely see the Filenotfound exception path, it is trying to do access/change intermediates folder content, Actually, the data bindings are created inside the build/generated instead of build/intermediates, So my answer is still valid as your android studio seems corrupt. It should not behave like this. When you uninstall it please remember to delete the .android folder in C:/Users/Kes.Walker/.android

before that, try to shorten the path like move your project to some other location such that the file path remains 128 characters and open the project in android studio.